# What is the right way to upload images to your website Node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web, upload, multer

Am not saying that i dont know how because i tried it before using multer and it works perfectly fine but the thing is these images get saved to a foldet called uploads with a namd and an id that i generatr using js
What i want to know : is this the propper way of doing it and if so wherr does that folder go to after hosting your website and does it contain alll the images from my website, i mean it will be a really large folder so where does it go to when hosting ??
PS: And another thing whenever i go to youtube or facebook etc i see a domain like i.ytimg.com containing these images so how is that acheived

Comment: Hi @Deadro, welcome to Stack Overflow. I strongly recommend you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly. SO is always willing to help with specific coding issues if you try something and can't make it work. Vague, general questions like this one generally don't do so well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my reply would be helpful, but the way I use it is I save the image in a mongoDB database (Buffer) and just load it from the database.

Comment: Oh yea i tried this method before but i heard that its not good for performance but correct me if i am wrong

Comment: It's the way I've always done it and didn't really search for other ways and thus can't really tell if it's the most proper way, I will also need to research more in order to tell you if its bad performance wise.